# Moment generating function of the natural sufficient statistics of Gamma distribution

Tags: self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family, cumulants

I have $X_1,X_2 ... X_n$ Gamma-distributed r.v with density:

[image]

First of all I showed, that Gamma distribution belongs to exponential family and can be represented in form

[image]

I found, that for Gamma distribution $B(\theta) = log(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is $\alpha/\beta$

Then we know, that moment generating function of the random variable $T(X)$ is given by $$M(t)=\exp\{B(\theta+t)-B(\theta)\}$$

Natural sufficient statistics for Gamma distribution is:

[image]

But I didn't understand what should I do next? Because Natural sufficient statistics is two dimensional it confuses me:

$M(T) = exp[log(\theta + T) - log(\theta)]$

and $T = [s,t]^\intercal$

Comment: Your representation of an exponential distribution is (a) unidimensional and (b) based on $y$ being the sufficient statistic. Check the literature or even the Wikipedia page for proper definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already recalled in [the answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/317307/7224) to a [previous question of yours](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/317266/7224) [and well-explained on Wikipedia](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/317266/7224), for any [exponential family](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/317266/7224), there exists a parameterisation such that the density of the family is$$f(x|\theta)=\exp\{\theta\cdot T(x)-\Psi(\theta)\}$$wrt a constant measure $\text{d}\mu(x)$, where the components of $T(\cdot)$ are linearly independent. The $\cdot$ in $\theta\cdot T(x)$ represents the scalar product, which means both $\theta$ and $T(x)$ are vector of the same dimension.

When you consider the density of the $\text{Ga}(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution,$$f(x|\alpha,\beta)=\dfrac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}\exp\{-\beta x\}\mathbb{I}_{(0,\infty)}(x)$$moving terms into the exponential leads to
\begin{align*}
f(x|\alpha,\beta)&=\dfrac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}\exp\{-\beta x\}\mathbb{I}_{(0,\infty)}(x)\\
&=\exp\{\log[\beta^\alpha] - \log \Gamma(\alpha)+[\alpha-1]\log x-\beta x\}\mathbb{I}_{(0,\infty)}(x)\\
&=\exp\{\underbrace{[\alpha-1]\log x-\beta x}_{\theta\cdot T(x)} + \underbrace{\log[\beta^\alpha] - \log \Gamma(\alpha)}_{\Psi(\theta)}\}\mathbb{I}_{(0,\infty)}(x)\\
\end{align*}
which suggests $\theta=(\alpha-1,\beta)$ as natural parameter and $T(x)=(\log x,-x)$ as sufficient statistic. (But other choices are possible.)

Hence, for this parameterisation of the $\text{Ga}(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution as an exponential family,
\begin{align*}
\Psi(\theta)&=-\log[\beta^\alpha] + \log \Gamma(\alpha)\\
&=-(\alpha-1+1)\log \beta + \log \Gamma(\alpha-1+1)\\
&= -[1+\theta_1]\log \theta_2 +\log \Gamma(1+\theta_1)
\end{align*}
as the cumulant moment function.